# Difference between highest and fifth highest salaries in SQL using Partition by

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have the data like this:

```
CREATE TABLE salaries AS
SELECT * FROM ( VALUES
  ('US'    , 'A', 3935),
  ('US'    , 'B', 7805),
  ('US'    , 'C', 2302),
  ('US'    , 'D', 6772),
  ('US'    , 'E', 3173),
  ('US'    , 'F', 7739),
  ('Japan' , 'G', 3881),
  ('Japan' , 'H', 1158),
  ('Japan' , 'I', 2591),
  ('Japan' , 'J', 3758),
  ('Japan' , 'K', 8710),
  ('Japan' , 'L', 3376),
  ('France', 'M', 5768),
  ('France', 'N', 9466),
  ('France', 'O', 1750),
  ('France', 'P', 1049),
  ('France', 'Q', 3479),
  ('France', 'R', 5305)
) AS t(country,employee,salary);
```

In order to find difference between maximum salary and fifth highest salary for every country I am trying the following approach:

```
select max(salary) over (partition by country) - rank(5) over (partition by country) 
from salaries
```

But it is throwing the following error:

"WITHIN GROUP is required for ordered-set aggregate function"

can anyone suggest any method without using any join?

Comment: why isnt working? what result you get? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: it is throwing an error: "WITHIN GROUP is required for ordered-set aggregate rank"

Comment: `rank()` doesnt receive parameter you need a `JOIN`

Comment: I agree Dudu, I would like to know what happens if one of the top-salaries is duplicated what you want...

Comment: as @DuduMarkovitz suggest you probably are looking for `row_number()` instead of `rank()`. You can see the differences [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Comment: P.s. `rank (1234) within group (order by salary)` is for finding the rank of a value within a group and NOT the Nth value

Comment: (FIX) Please add 5 records where country = US and salary = 7739 and then check the answers

Comment: Also add a country with only two employees.

Comment: using coalesce is giving the right answer when number of employees is <5  but when number of employees is >5 and number of distinct salaries is <5 then it is just giving the max salary as output. may be row number along with order by will solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select      country
           ,max(salary) - max(case dr when 5 then salary end) as salary_diff

from       (select      country     
                       ,salary
                       ,dense_rank() over (partition by country order by salary desc) as dr

            from        salaries
            ) s

group by    country
```

Comment: This assumes he wants rank. I don't actually think it's a *bad* submission, I just don't think it's what he wants. If we're trying to find the fifth largest salary in a country, it doesn't make much sense to use rank(). But, by any means, you feel passionately about rank and should should describe it in your answer.

Comment: I commented to the OP and ask to add some rows to the sample, which will give him the ability to choose the desired solution.

Comment: I haven't thought about the duplicate salaries for now. but yeah this works for distinct salaries.

Comment: Same problem, you are not sure if 5th element exist.  So at least you should use `COALESCE(MAX....`  or add `ELSE 0`

Comment: Nope. I would like to get NULL in this case.

Comment: yeah using coalesce will help it better in handling the exception in case 5th element is missing.

Comment: Once you do that you loose information unless you add another column that indicates that no 5th salary was found

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a [WINDOW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) that defines what you want (partition by country, order by salary descending)
2. Calculate the `max(salary)` over that window
3. Calculate the [`nth_value`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) from the top (because they're sorted by salary descending)

A special note is that `WINDOWS` have ranges and rows. They detail how the calculation is performed WITHIN that window. Here we have to UNBOUND the `WINDOW` to get the `nth_value()` to work. Normally, it calculates on everything thus seen so nth_value only kicks in if it is has seen that row -- but we can make it see ahead.

Code,

```
SELECT *
  , max(salary) OVER w1 - nth_value(salary,5) OVER w1 AS max_minus_fifth_highest
FROM foo
WINDOW w1 AS (
  PARTITION BY (country)
  ORDER BY SALARY desc
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
)
ORDER BY country;
```

[Sql Demo](http://rextester.com/KRAPU18067)

Comment: A valid point, however the question doesn't address that case.

Comment: In addition it returns all original rows

Comment: He doesn't actually say what he wants as output either. This question should have probably been closed.

Comment: He uses a WINDOW function, I just figured that's what he wanted.

Comment: @EvanCarroll You dont close a question for that, you ask for clarification on the comments.

Comment: You can do that when it's closed.

Comment: @EvanCarroll thanks for the new function "nth_value". never knew about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select country, max_sal - salary
from (
     select country, salary, 
            max(salary) over (partition by country) max_sal,
           case when (row_number() over (partition by country
                                         order by salary desc)) = 5 
                then 1 
           end fifth
from table
) t where fifth is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/TQKZ32044)**

```
with fifth as (
     SELECT country, "salary",
            rank() over (partition by "country" order by "salary" desc)  rnk
     FROM salaries
)
SELECT *
FROM salaries s
JOIN fifth f
  ON s.country = f.country
 AND f.rnk = 5
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: There is no guarantee that RANK = 5 exists (even if there are more than 5 distinct salaries!) or that it exists and unique